# I've Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my PC and am unable to dial up 3.5G connect wireless modem and have ISP (Idea Gujarat,India)

Tags: boot, networking, dual-boot, mount, usb-modem

I've Ubuntu and Windows 7 Ultimate in dual boot. Since I was unable to open 3.5G's file so that I could copy linux_dialer to `root/usr` folder and so I copy that folder in one of the local disk and able to paste that folder to `usr`.
And then I install it by clicking `run in terminal` as per manual and then when it came to eject the modem, shows an error.....

[image: error caused]

and then I try to `run in terminal` the `dial up` file and shows error
[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you tell us your ISP (internet service provider), modem model and your country.

Comment: Idea (Gujarat, India) iball 3.5G connect wireless modem

Comment: Edit this in question.